# Pandas dataframe insert rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got a problem dealing with dataframe.
I want to insert rows in DF and modify its related values:

for example I have

```
time  value
0  10:00      2
1  11:00      4
2  12:00      6
3  13:00      8
```

and the ideal result should be:

```
time  value
0  10:00      1
1  11:00      2
0  10:00      1
1  11:00      2
2  12:00      6
3  13:00      8
```

Which duplicate first two rows and then divide its value evenly.

The code can only append rows but how to modify its values in a faster way?
`df[0:2].append(df[0:2]).append(df[2:])`

Answer (score 3):

```
first_two = df[: 2]
first_two.value = first_two.value / 2

df = pd.concat([first_two, first_two, df[2:]])
```

**Edit**

as [Paul H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1552748/paul-h) points out below, it's better touse [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) for this stuff.

Comment: Better to use the `.iloc` attribute here. IOW: `first_two = df.iloc[:2]`